# Derivative of $f\left(f_{1}\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right),\dots,f_{n}\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right)\right)$ with respect to $x_{i}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

In general, given a function $f\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right)$ and functions $f_{1}\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right)$, $\dots$, $f_{n}\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right)$, is there a rule to find the partial derivative of $f\left(f_{1}\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right),\dots,f_{n}\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right)\right)$ with respect to $x_{i}$?

Comment: Consider the function $F = (f_1, \ldots, f_n),$ so that $F' = (f_1', \ldots, f_n')$ and the chain rule implies $(f \circ F)' = (f' \circ F) \circ F';$ therefore, $\partial_i (f \circ F) = (f' \circ F) \partial_i F = (f' \circ F) (\partial_i f_1, \ldots, \partial_i f_n) = \sum_j ((\partial_j f) \circ F) \partial_i f_j.$

Comment: @WillM. Sorry, I'm not too familiar with your notation $\partial_{i}$ and $\partial_{j}$. Is $\partial_{i}\left(f\circ F\right)$ the partial derivative of $f\circ F$ with respect to $x_{i}$? What is $\partial_{j}f$ in the summation?

Comment: $\partial_i f = D_i f$

Comment: If you want the "dumbo chain rule" (as my professor used to call it) then consider $f_i = y_i$ and so what I wrote above is $\sum_j (\partial f/ \partial y_j) (\partial y_j/ \partial x_i).$

Comment: @WillM. ah okay got it. Thanks.